# ASP.NET Core как запретить для страницы подтягивать шапку и футер с _Layout.chtml

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, razor

Делаю приложение ASP.NET Core по типу MVC, шаблон шапки и футера для всех страниц находится в файле `_Layout.chtml`. Но нужно на странице с авторизацией убрать шаблонную шапку и футер.

```
@model App.Models.LoginModel

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm">
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col">
               </div>
               <div class="col-6">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Войти в систему</button>
               </div>
               <div class="col">
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="alert alert-danger row m-3" role="alert" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Аналогов `include` на самой страницы нет, только подключается модель

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить вот это:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

в начале страницы, на которой не хотите видеть шапку и футер.

`Layout` позволяет нам указывать мастер-страницы. Мастер страницы это представления, которые позволяют описать элементы, отображающиеся на всех страницах сайта. В проекте может быть несколько мастер страниц, тогда в представлениях мы должны указать путь к мастер-странице:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Если мы не используем мастер-страницу, то мы указываем `Layout = null;`.

Так же у нас есть страница `_ViewStart.cshtml`. Код этой страницы выполняется до кода любого из представлений, расположенных в том же каталоге. Данный файл последовательно применяется к каждому представлению, находящемуся в одном каталоге.
Обычно в нём как раз и расположено подключение мастер-страницы:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

поэтому этого подключения нету внутри ваших представлений.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало